# Dynamic SVG background using javascript window functions

Tags: javascript, dynamic, svg, window

I am trying to set my background as an SVG image. However, I want the size to be dynamically constructed using the javascript window functions. Here is the logic...

```
<script>
  function getWidth()
  {
    var w=window.innerWidth
    || document.documentElement.clientWidth
    || document.body.clientWidth;

    return w;

  }

  function getHeight()
  {
    var h=window.innerHeight
    || document.documentElement.clientHeight
    || document.body.clientHeight;

    return h;

  }

</script>

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

**var wid = getWidth();
  <rect width=wid height="100"**
  style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: You need to change this configuration while resizing the window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS3 is the solution.

```
html, body
{
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background:url(../Images/books.svg);
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```